# Modify date popup structure

Tags: 7, theming, hooks, datetime

I would like to modify the date popup structure, in the image below you can see how date module builds the element. Drupal's default label is hidden, and it generates other to display the title. I want to show that label, and hide the date module label. Where should i modify this? Using some hooks in a .module, create a custom template or just overwrite it with css? Thanks all for help!

PD: This change must concern to every page in my site.

[image]

Comment: This is for D7 or D8 ?

Comment: Yep, i forgot it. Drupal 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override `theme_date_popup` in your theme or custom module.
See the following [tutorial](https://www.hashbangcode.com/article/overriding-drupal-7-theme-functions-module-files) how to do it.

Comment: You are welcome, i'm glad that help.